# Select query where query values can be null

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, select, null

My table "mytable" in MS SQL Server looks like:

```
|Id|ka|kb|kc  |kd
|1 | 1| 1|NULL|NULL
|2 | 1| 1|1   |NULL
|3 | 1| 1|1   |1
```

where Id, ka kb can not be null but kc and kd can be null.

Can I select from mytable with variables that also can be null **?**

```
int? varka = 1, varkb = 1, varkc = null, varkd = null;

select Id from mytable where ka = varka and kb = varkb and kc = varkc and kd = varkd
```

My desired Id from mytable is "1", only "1" but I am getting a NULL in C#, or no result in T-SQL.

Comment: No, if you are writing T-SQL, then *almost always* you are going to be using ANSI-null behavior, which means null never equals anything: not even null - you need to use `is null` to test for nulls. It isn't clear how you are adding the parameters, though, so I can't be clear what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a null-safe equality. In standard SQL, we have operator `IS DISTINCT FROM`, but SQL Server does not supports it (and provides not equivalent operator).

So we are left with boolean logic:

```
select id
from mytable 
where 
    ka = varka 
    and kb = varkb 
    and ( (kc is null and varkc is null) or kc = varkc )
    and ( (kd is null and varkd is null) or kd = varkd )
```